# Boost ASIO error "Host not found" on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, boost, boost-asio

I have an application which sends a multicast message out across the local network once a second. This code is working fine on both Windows and macOS and it works fine on iOS unless the network isn't connected to the internet.

```
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(m_IOservice);
        boost::system::error_code ec;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(boost::asio::ip::host_name(),"");
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator it = resolver.resolve(query, ec);
        boost::asio::ip::address interface_ip_address;

        while(it!=boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator())
        {
            interface_ip_address = (it++)->endpoint().address();
            if(interface_ip_address.is_v4())
            {
                // Message sending code here
            }
        }
```

The problem happens at resolver.resolve() where I get an exception with "Host not found (authoritative)" as the error.

I'm not sure I really understand why this error is happening, and certainly not how to fix it. Can anyone shed any light on it for me?

Comment: Hey where you able to get the boost asio library working on iOS devices ? Do they cause any issues with the run loop.

Comment: Yes, we got it working and we've had no problems. The boost ethernet code runs in a separate thread then passes the data (in a thread-safe way) to the main run loop thread to handle

Comment: Thanks. Just to make it clear, you are not tweaking anything in the io_services event loop ? asio gets the data, and you just pass it to a different thread.

Comment: Yes, exactly that. No tweaks to the io_services event loop. The Boost asio code is actually very simple and is very reliable.

Answer (score 0):

What does host_name return? Likely it returns a name that doesn't resolve.

If you just want localhost, use `boost::asio::ip::addressv4()` or even `boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1")`.

Alternatively add an entry to your `/etc/hosts` file:

```
 127.0.0.1 thehostnametoresolvetolocalhost
```